# How to count every month records from Table1 and Store it in Table2

Tags: php, sql, database

Let's Say I have 2 tables

In Table1 I have 3 columns named as

**Table1**

```
Id | Name | Date (Format: 12-01-2019)
1     ABC     22-08-2019
2     XYZ     23-07-2019
```

Now My Question is How to store the Month wise count in another Table(i.e, Table2)

Expected Result:

**Table 2**

```
Month      |     Count
08/Aug             1
07/July            1
```

I searched many queries but I didn't find a better one

**Can anyone provide me this sql query?**

**OR**

If can you provide SQL query which stores all these count in separate column in **Table1** with an extra column

Comment: I removed the incompatible database tags.  Please tag with the database you are really using.

Comment: Why would you want to store the results in a second table, when you could get the same results with an aggregate query?

Comment: I think the question is: Why would you store that in a table when it is something you can return quite easily from a query whenever you want that data. If you store it in another table it will only ever be out of date or wrong due to someone changing the original data and NOT changing the second table

Comment: Yeah if it is possible in the same table also no issue for me but I need exact sql query. I tried many queries but no result

Comment: @SraVaN What sql flavor are you using? MySQL, Oracle sql, etc.?

Comment: Create a view instead. Or have a computed column. (Depending on the dbms.)

Comment: _If you need the exact query_ Give us a starter for 10 and show us what you have tried

Comment: Why is everyone assuming that it doesn't make sense to store this in another table, it's just a time-memory tradeoff, and you could be aggregating old data before deleting it

Answer (score 0):

```
merge into table_2 tgt
using 
    (select trunc(dt, 'month') dt, count(*) cnt
     from table_1
     group by trunc(dt, 'month')
    ) src on (tgt.dt = src.dt)
when not matched then insert (tgt.dt, tgt.cnt)
                      values (src.dt, src.cnt);
```

Comment: Yea, maybe, but WHY would you store that in another table only for it to be wrong potentially in less than a milli second

Answer (score 0):

```
INSERT INTO table2(month,count)
SELECT 
   MONTH(Date) AS m, COUNT(DISTINCT Id)
FROM 
   table1 GROUP BY m;
```

Comment: Yea, maybe, but WHY would you store that in another table only for it to be wrong potentially in less than a milli second

Answer (score 0):

This can be done in one query

```
Insert into Table2 (Column1, Column2)
Select Count(*), DATEColumn from Table1 group by DATEColumn
```

I am not sure which database your are using this work on MSSQL.

Comment: Yea, maybe, but WHY would you store that in another table only for it to be wrong potentially in less than a milli second

Comment: It depend on data size. traffic flow .. sometime we need to store data and make it ready for quick access instead of run time calculations.